# How to position UserControl inside of a Panel when it is added at run-time?

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, panel

I have a dialog form with a mixture of design-time and run-time added controls. Each of these controls is hosted in a Panel. Each panel has FillStyle.Top set.

At run time I add a UserControl to a panel:

```
public NetworkDiscoveryDialog(CSNetworkDiscovery networkDiscovery) : this()
{
    NetworkDiscovery = networkDiscovery;
    SnmpCommunitiesUserControl = new SnmpCommunitiesUserControl(NetworkDiscovery.SnmpCommunitiesSetting);
    panel2.Controls.Add(SnmpCommunitiesUserControl);
}

public partial class SnmpCommunitiesUserControl : UserControl
{
    public SnmpSetting SnmpSetting { get; set; }

    public SnmpCommunitiesUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left);
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }

    public SnmpCommunitiesUserControl(SnmpSetting snmpSetting)
        : this()
    {
        SnmpSetting = snmpSetting;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, SnmpCommunitiesUserControl does not have the same position as the controls which were added at design-time.

I have tried:

- Setting the Panel's margin as well as well as padding.
- Setting the UserControl's margin as well as padding.
- Anchor and Dock settings.

None of these seem to have any effect on the run-time added UserControl.

Previously, I was passing a 'Location' parameter to my UserControl's constructor. This allowed me to set the Location of the UserControl, but was not a maintainable solution.

How should I be going about doing this?

EDIT:

My current solution is to nest a a second panel inside of the first panel. I clear all margins and padding for both panels. The parent panel has Dock.Top with its child have Dock.Fill. Then, I set the child's Left/Right padding to 10. This causes the run-time added control to appear in the proper place. I'm not happy with this solution, though.

[image]

Comment: @KRAZE:  it is a Windows based application.

Comment: My bad I don't know why I didn't see that my mind was seeing aspnet.. sorry about that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set Location and Size Properties by yourself or you can set Dock property of the new control. Another way is change your host panel to the StackLayoutPanel or TableLayoutPanel.

Comment: The dock property is already set to Fill. The UserControl is to be used by multiple dialogs. As such, I need the position to be able to be dynamically-inferred to prevent maintenance issues. I don't want to have to manually set the Location property of my UserControl for each dialog. It was my understanding that a group of panels should function similarly to that of a TableLayoutPanel if the dialog is not able to be resized. Is this incorrect?

Comment: You are correct but the control tree is not so easy to fill. The controls' ordering is very impotant to correct layout.

Comment: Try to investigate the form layout generated by form's designer through View->Other Windows->Document Outline. It will provide lot of information to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set absolute position, u should set the Location property to your position and set dock to none.
`control.Location = new Point(x, y);

 control.Dock = DockStyle.None;`